# How to train and tune an artificial multilayer perceptron neural network using Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am building my first artificial multilayer perceptron neural network using Keras.

This is my input data:

[image]

This is my code which I used to build my initial model which basically follows the Keras example code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=14, init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=20, batch_size=16)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/20
1213/1213 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1760     
Epoch 2/20
1213/1213 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1840     
Epoch 3/20
1213/1213 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1816     
Epoch 4/20
1213/1213 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1915     
Epoch 5/20
1213/1213 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1928     
Epoch 6/20
1213/1213 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1964     
Epoch 7/20
1213/1213 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1948     
Epoch 8/20
1213/1213 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1971     
Epoch 9/20
1213/1213 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1899     
Epoch 10/20
1213/1213 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1957     
Epoch 11/20
1213/1213 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1923     
Epoch 12/20
1213/1213 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1910     
Epoch 13/20
1213/1213 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2104     
Epoch 14/20
1213/1213 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1976     
Epoch 15/20
1213/1213 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1979     
Epoch 16/20
1213/1213 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2036     
Epoch 17/20
1213/1213 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2019     
Epoch 18/20
1213/1213 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1978     
Epoch 19/20
1213/1213 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1954     
Epoch 20/20
1213/1213 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1949
```

How do I train and tune this model and get my code to output my best predictive model? I am new to neural networks and am just wholly confused as to what is the next step after building the model. I know I want to optimize it, but I'm not sure which features to tweak or if I am supposed to do it manually or how to write code to do so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some things that you could do are:

- Change your loss function from `mean_squared_error` to `binary_crossentropy`. `mean_squared_error` is intended for regression, but you want to classify your data.
- Add `show_accuracy=True` to your `fit()` function, which outputs the accuracy of your model at every epoch. That information is probably more useful to you than just the loss value.
- Add `validation_split=0.2` to your `fit()` function. Currently you are only training on a training set and validating on nothing. That's a no-go in machine learning as you can't be sure that your model hasn't simply memorized the correct answers for your dataset (without really understanding why these answers are correct).
- Change from Obama/Romney to Democrat/Republican and add data from previous elections. ~1200 examples is a pretty small dataset for neural networks. Also add columns with valuable information, like unemployment rate or population *density*. Note that quite some of the values (like population number) are probably similar to providing the name of the state, so e.g. your net will likely learn that Texas means `Republican`.
- If you haven't done that already, normalize all your values to the range of 0 to 1 (by subtracting from each value the minimum of the column and then dividing by the (max - min) of the column). Neural networks can handle normalized data better than unnormalized data.
- Try `Adam` and `Adagrad` instead of `SGD`. Sometimes they perform better. (See [documentation about optimizers](http://keras.io/optimizers/).)
- Try `Activation('relu')`, `LeakyReLU`, `PReLU` and `ELU` instead of `Activation('tanh')`. Tanh is rarely the best choice. (See [advanced activation functions](http://keras.io/layers/advanced_activations/).)
- Try increasing/decreasing your dense layers sizes (e.g. from `64` to `128`). Also try adding/removing layers.
- Try adding `BatchNormalization` layers (before the `Activation` layers). (See [documentation](http://keras.io/layers/normalization/).)
- Try changing the dropout rates (e.g. from `0.5` to `0.25`).